# Escaping quotes in output string in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm working on an API project using Terraform 0.14.2.  I want to create an output that prints a debug CURL command that I can use while developing the API.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to output

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"test": "yes"}' https://foo.bar.baz`

My Terraform output looks like this:

```
output "test" {
  value = "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '${jsonencode({test = "yes"})}' https://foo.bar.baz"
}
```

Terraform is happy with this, but it generates the following actual output

`cur -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"test\": \"yes\"}' https://foo.bar.baz`

I've tried to write the JSON manually:

```
output "test" {
  value = "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"test\" = \"yes\"}' https://foo.bar.baz"
}
```

But I get the same output.  Does string escaping work differently in terraform than every other language?  For an even simpler example, take this terraform:

```
output "quote" {
  value = "\""
}
```

This outputs `"\""` I would expect it to output `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is **raw output**. You have to explicitly request such an output:

```
terraform output -raw test
```

But, i'm not sure if you can force `terraform apply` to use raw outputs, instead of the escaped ones.

Comment: Indeed, the `terraform apply` output is for presentation only, so it uses syntax similar to the Terraform language itself. `terraform output -raw` is, as Marcin says, the intended way to get the raw value for integration with other software.